# Hong Kong Ubuntu Updates URL

Tags: 16.04

I wanted to know if Ubuntu has regional Asia updates URL. The reason is because I have a few servers in Hong Kong and when trying to access the US URLs I get the below errors.

```
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [3,224 B]
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [3,224 B]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [3,224 B]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [3,224 B]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
```

Comment: The Hong Kong Ubuntu Server is located at hk.archive.ubuntu.com with Port 80.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [list of archive mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) on Launchpad, with multiple options in China and Hong Kong.

Comment: Hi - I put a few URLs under the source list file and still get same errors. see below.                 Get:5 http://mirrors.njupt.edu.cn/ubuntu xenial InRelease [3,221 B]
Err:5 http://mirrors.njupt.edu.cn/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Fetched 16.1 kB in 0s (17.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: You have a network configuration issue then most likely. Are you required to go through a proxy? Is it properly authenticated? See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/46796732 for some more info. You'll likely need to contact whomever administers the network those servers are on, and not something we can solve here.

Comment: Hi All - I was able to resolve the issue buy putting a proxy under the environment file under etc. I was not sure that was going to work since the proxy is in the US, but it did work. So thanks to all for your answers.